# Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: resolver could not resolve to a file

Tags: zend-framework, php-5.3

I am using zend framework 2.1.5 and I want to send email with custom email template. here is my code

```
$view = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface');
$viewModel = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
$template = 'forgot_password.phtml';
$viewModel->setTemplate($template)
        ->setVariables(array('data' => $data));

$content = $view->render($viewModel);
```

getting an error `Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "forgot_password.phtml"; resolver could not resolve to a file`

Comment: Where is the file located?

Comment: What's the full path to it?

Comment: \vendor\Mymodule\library\Mymodule\Mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note : Set resolver to your view like as below

```
$view = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface');


    $resolver = new \Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack();
            $resolver->setPaths(array(
                'mailTemplate' => __DIR__ . 'TEMPLATE PATH'  
            ));

            $view->setResolver($resolver); 


    $viewModel = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
    $template = 'forgot_password.phtml';
    $viewModel->setTemplate($template)
            ->setVariables(array('data' => $data));

    $content = $view->render($viewModel);
```

This may help you.